# Table Not Working

Tags: tables

I found this old code for a table, but I do not understand why it is not working. Could you help?

```
\documentclass{article} 
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{.25in} 
\setlength{\textwidth}{5.5in} 
\setlength{\topmargin}{0.50in} 
\setlength{\textheight}{9.00in} 
\pagestyle{empty} 
\begin{document} 
\input table 
\BeginTable 

\def\C{\JustCenter} 
\def\L{\JustLeft} 
\def\R{\JustRight} 
\BeginFormat 
|   l   |  l  | cn[-0.00] | cn[-0.00] | cn[-0.00] | cn[-0.00] | cn[-0.00] | 
\EndFormat 
" \use7 \C \bf TABLE 4 " \\+02 
" \use7 \C \bf Influence of State Variables on Asset Demands " \\+11 \_3 
" {} " \C State Variables: " \C Constant " \C $AR_t$     " \C $y_t$     " \C $(d-p)_t$ " \C $spr_t$ " \\+23 \_2 
" \use3 \L 1953/Q2 - 1999/Q3, Quarterly " {} " {} " {} " {} " \\+42 
" \use3 \L $~\gamma =1, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $ " {} " {} " {} " {} " \\+34 
" ~~Stock" Total Demand " 272.77  " 292.42  " 296.33  " 303.41  " 302.79 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00 " \\+12 
" ~~Bond" Total Demand " 172.93  " 162.73  " 160.07  " 160.67  " 171.01 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00 " \\+12 
" ~~Cash" Total Demand " -345.70  " -355.15  " -356.40  " -364.08  " -373.80 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00  " 0.00 " \\+15 \_1 
" \use3 \L $~\gamma =2, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $ " {} " {} " {} " {} " \\+34 
" ~~Stock" Total Demand " 135.52  " 146.02  " 149.62  " 246.07  " 246.61 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 0.20  " 1.95  " 94.91  " 95.77 " \\+12 
" ~~Bond" Total Demand " 82.13  " 33.53  " -7.22  " 6.25  " -8.17 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " -43.86  " -83.35  " -70.18  " -90.00 " \\+12 
" ~~Cash" Total Demand " -117.65  " -79.55  " -42.39  " -152.32  " -138.44 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 43.66  " 81.41  " -24.73  " -5.77 " \\+15 \_1 
" \use3 \L $~\gamma =5, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $ " {} " {} " {} " {} " \\+34 
" ~~Stock" Total Demand " 53.17  " 56.52  " 57.40  " 157.64  " 160.51 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " -1.34  " -1.08  " 97.83  " 100.84 " \\+12 
" ~~Bond" Total Demand " 27.65  " -3.94  " -15.70  " -43.70  " -94.24 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " -30.13  " -41.47  " -69.59  " -122.57 " \\+12 
" ~~Cash" Total Demand " 19.18  " 47.42  " 58.30  " -13.94  " 33.73 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 31.47  " 42.55  " -28.24  " 21.72 " \\+15 \_1 
" \use3 \L $~\gamma =20, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $ " {} " {} " {} " {} " \\+34 
" ~~Stock" Total Demand " 12.00  " 12.01  " 11.47  " 59.37  " 59.54 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " -1.88  " -2.41  " 45.23  " 45.46 " \\+12 
" ~~Bond" Total Demand " 0.41  " -11.28  " 3.61  " -19.55  " -39.95 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " -11.86  " 3.03  " -20.17  " -41.53 " \\+12 
" ~~Cash" Total Demand " 87.59  " 99.27  " 84.92  " 60.18  " 80.41 " \\+11 
"  {} " Hedging Demand " 0.00  " 13.74  " -0.62  " -25.06  " -3.94 " \\+15 \_1 
\EndTable 
\bigskip \footnotesize{\bf Note}: $AR_t$ = real returns on T-Bills, excess return on stocks, and excess return on bonds; $y_t$ = nominal yield on T-Bills; $(d-p)_t$ = log dividend-price ratio; $spr_t$ = yield spread. The bond is a 5-year nominal bond in the quarterly dataset and a 20-year in the annual dataset. \normalsize \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. What's in the file `table.tex`? How are `\BeginTable`, `\EndTable`, `\BeginFormat`,  and `\EndFormat` defined?

Comment: that is TABLE syntax https://pctex.com/manuals/tableSelection.pdf which is almost never used with latex. I would advise using a standard latex `tabular`

Comment: note that manual is dated 1988 so it predates latex2e by 5 years

Comment: "not working"  does not allow anyone to help, what error message did you get, have you installed `table.tex` (which is not in standard tex distributions but is available from the pctex company website)

Answer (score 1):

As [David Carlisle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle) mentioned its table environment defined in a different manner. If there are not much tables, you can switch back to usual `tabular` environment. Here I have used `longtable` environment so that it will not have any affect on pagebreaks. I have also used `booktabs` to style it.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllll}
        \caption{Influence of State Variables on Asset Demands}
    \label{my-label}\\
    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{State Variables:}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Constant}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$AR_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{ $y_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$(d-p)_t$}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{$spr_t$}} \\
    \endfirsthead
    %
    \endhead
    %
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{1953/Q2 - 1999/Q3, Quarterly}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 \\ \toprule
    \multicolumn{7}{l}{\textbf{$~\gamma =1, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $}}                                                                                                                                                                                                                   \\\toprule 
    ~~Stock                       & Total Demand                                  & 272.77                                & 292.42                              & 296.33                                & 303.41                                    & 302.79                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 0                                   & 0                                     & 0                                         & 0                                       \\
    ~~Bond                        & Total Demand                                  & 172.93                                & 162.73                              & 160.07                                & 160.67                                    & 171.01                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 0                                   & 0                                     & 0                                         & 0                                       \\
    ~~Cash                        & Total Demand                                  & -345.7                                & -355.15                             & -356.4                                & -364.08                                   & -373.8                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 0                                   & 0                                     & 0                                         & 0                                       \\ \toprule 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{$~\gamma =2, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $}}                                               & \textbf{}                           & \textbf{}                             & \textbf{}                                 & \textbf{}                               \\ \toprule 
    ~~Stock                       & Total Demand                                  & 135.52                                & 146.02                              & 149.62                                & 246.07                                    & 246.61                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 0.2                                 & 1.95                                  & 94.91                                     & 95.77                                   \\
    ~~Bond                        & Total Demand                                  & 82.13                                 & 33.53                               & -7.22                                 & 6.25                                      & -8.17                                   \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & -43.86                              & -83.35                                & -70.18                                    & -90                                     \\
    ~~Cash                        & Total Demand                                  & -117.65                               & -79.55                              & -42.39                                & -152.32                                   & -138.44                                 \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 43.66                               & 81.41                                 & -24.73                                    & -5.77                                   \\ \toprule 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{$~\gamma =5, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $}}                                               & \textbf{}                           & \textbf{}                             & \textbf{}                                 & \textbf{}                               \\ \toprule 
    ~~Stock                       & Total Demand                                  & 53.17                                 & 56.52                               & 57.4                                  & 157.64                                    & 160.51                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & -1.34                               & -1.08                                 & 97.83                                     & 100.84                                  \\
    ~~Bond                        & Total Demand                                  & 27.65                                 & -3.94                               & -15.7                                 & -43.7                                     & -94.24                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & -30.13                              & -41.47                                & -69.59                                    & -122.57                                 \\
    ~~Cash                        & Total Demand                                  & 19.18                                 & 47.42                               & 58.3                                  & -13.94                                    & 33.73                                   \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 31.47                               & 42.55                                 & -28.24                                    & 21.72                                   \\ \toprule 
    \multicolumn{3}{l}{\textbf{$~\gamma =20, \psi = 1, \rho =0.92^{1/4}  $}}                                              & \textbf{}                           & \textbf{}                             & \textbf{}                                 & \textbf{}                               \\ \toprule 
    ~~Stock                       & Total Demand                                  & 12                                    & 12.01                               & 11.47                                 & 59.37                                     & 59.54                                   \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & -1.88                               & -2.41                                 & 45.23                                     & 45.46                                   \\
    ~~Bond                        & Total Demand                                  & 0.41                                  & -11.28                              & 3.61                                  & -19.55                                    & -39.95                                  \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & -11.86                              & 3.03                                  & -20.17                                    & -41.53                                  \\
    ~~Cash                        & Total Demand                                  & 87.59                                 & 99.27                               & 84.92                                 & 60.18                                     & 80.41                                   \\
    & Hedging Demand                                & 0                                     & 13.74                               & -0.62                                 & -25.06                                    & -3.94                  \\ \bottomrule                 
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

I hope that you will be able to clean the empty `\textbf{}`s.